# azure-iot-sdk-c deserialize JSON payload

Tags: c, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm getting started with the Azure IoT SDK C-Library by using the [IoT_Hub Device Method samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_device_method/iothub_client_sample_device_method.c).

Does anybody know if the SDK provides a function to deserialize the JSON message payload? There are some good [examples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/serializer/samples/simplesample_mqtt/simplesample_mqtt.c) for payload serialization to JSON, but I wasn't able to find the counterpart.

I'm quite sure the SDK has some functionalities for JSON deserialization, e.g. something like:

```
BEGIN_NAMESPACE(WeatherStation);

DECLARE_MODEL(ContosoAnemometer, 
  WITH_DATA(ascii_char_ptr, DeviceId), 
  WITH_DATA(int, WindSpeed), 
  WITH_DATA(float, Temperature), 
  WITH_DATA(float, Humidity), 
  WITH_ACTION(TurnFanOn)
); 

END_NAMESPACE(WeatherStation);


static int DeviceMethodCallback(const char* method_name, const unsigned char* payload, ...) 
{ 
    (void)userContextCallback; 

    ContosoAnemometer* myWeather = CREATE_MODEL_INSTANCE(WeatherStation, ContosoAnemometer);
    DESERIALIZE(myWeather, payload)

    printf("Device Id: %i\r\n", myWeather->DeviceId);

    // etc. etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Azure IoT SDK for C,it uses serializer library to serialize messages to send, but there is no couterpart(DESERIALIZE) for receiving messages.Please see 
[more about serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-sdk-c-serializer). In serializer component, you will find **jsondecoder.c**, it defines some method for decode json data.

And more, you will find the [parson](https://github.com/kgabis/parson/tree/bef4969d258d5bcce0d686b7bf514550e2ac346d) component. It can be used to deserialize the object from json string.You can refer to the following code.

**jsonstr**

```
{"desString":"P7svG%2BLoUZEbB8Le5jP1%2BpuX2OVWLE4xWMzFcYFCRvNvDlcFVm%2B8z2VFO%2F%2BaEB8UAMa%2FZ0GGhooGNMWFE98Zmw%3D%3D","caller":{"mobile":"13996130361"},"accountId":"b5091dc91d700c6bf714e5fc446797d3","tmpTime":1428545890,"otherParam":"{id:12}","participant":[{"mobile":"18623582801"}],"servletUrl":"http://192.168.1.1:8090/xdr"}
```

**C Code**

```
JSON_Value *root_value=NULL;
root_value = json_parse_string(jsonstr);
JSON_Object *root_object;
if(json_value_get_type(root_value) == JSONObject)
{
    root_object = json_value_get_object(root_value);
    const char *desString = json_object_get_string(root_object, "desString");
    if(desString!=NULL)strncpy(pPost->desString,desString,LENGTH128-1);
    const char *accountId = json_object_get_string(root_object, "accountId");
    if(accountId!=NULL)strncpy(pPost->accountId,accountId,LENGTH32);
    double tmpTime = json_object_get_number(root_object, "tmpTime");
    const char *caller = json_object_dotget_string(root_object,"caller.mobile");
    if(caller!=NULL)strncpy(pPost->caller,caller,LENGTH16-1);
    const char *servletUrl = json_object_dotget_string(root_object,"servletUrl");
    if(servletUrl!=NULL)strncpy(pPost->servletUrl,servletUrl,LENGTH128-1);
    const char *otherParam = json_object_dotget_string(root_object,"otherParam");
    if(otherParam!=NULL)strncpy(pPost->otherParam,otherParam,LENGTH128-1);

    JSON_Array *array;
    array = json_object_get_array(root_object, "participant");
    int i =0;
    for(i;i<json_array_get_count(array);i++)
    {
        JSON_Object *tmp = json_array_get_object(array,i);
        if(tmp!=NULL)
        {
            const char *mobile = json_object_get_string(tmp,"mobile");
            if(mobile!=NULL)strncpy(pPost->callee,mobile,LENGTH16-1);
        }
    }
}
if(root_value)json_value_free(root_value);
```

Comment: Dear Michael, thank you very much for your helpful answere! Perfect, it works :-)